# dotnet core REST API post data can't read in XML from List in request

Tags: xml, post, .net-core

I created a dotnet core rest api which can serve both XML and JSON here is my Request modal

```
public class ReqBlackListData
{


    public ReqBlackListData()
    {
        usersInfo = new List<userInfo>();
    }
    public List<userInfo> usersInfo { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    ///request comming for Motor or nonmotor 
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public string module { get; set; }
}
```

above class i used to accept request in XML and JSON in JSON every thing okay when i call in XML usersInfo listnot able carry data in post `(Count = 0)` please help me to find issue.

Comment: Do you add a XML Formatter?? See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-web-api-configure-formats/

Comment: here is my startup.cs config public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

         
          
            services.AddMvc(options =>
               {
                   options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                   options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
                   //options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
                   //options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());

               }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();}

Comment: yes added in startup.cs page

Comment: So asp.net core should handle XML input automatically. Ensure that you input xml is valid and you content type of your request is application/xml.

Comment: yes and content type also application/xml FYI when make post with XML in manage to capture module data but only list data missing

Comment: Ahh, missed that. You could try to add xml attributes to the model class to specify the deserialization. For example [XmlArray]

Comment: added like this still can't 
public ReqBlackListData()
        {
            usersInfo = new List<userInfo>();
        }
        [XmlArray("usersInfo")]
        [XmlArrayItem("userInfo")]
        public List<userInfo> usersInfo { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi am very sorry i find the solution already and it is nothing with Xml attributes (XmlArray etc) issues is i just missed list 
my request like this

```
<usersInfo>
        <identityNo>string</identityNo>
        <identityType>string</identityType>
        <passport>string</passport>
        <dob>string</dob>
        <fullName>string</fullName>
        <extraDetails>string</extraDetails>
        <nationality>string</nationality>
</usersInfo>
```

bu by right here usersInfo is my list and userInfo is my class

```
<usersInfo>
   <userInfo>
          <identityNo>string</identityNo>
          <identityType>string</identityType>
          <passport>string</passport>
          <dob>string</dob>
          <fullName>string</fullName>
          <extraDetails>string</extraDetails>
          <nationality>string</nationality>
     <userInfo>
</usersInfo>
```